# Async API Request to Return all Results

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to return all the results everytime from the API. Instead, my results vary. The for loop skips over requests and return a random number of records returned. Can anyone help?

I have tried using the async and await function. I have also tried to implement the promise.all but do not think i am properly setting it up for the api request.

```
// Get all ref codes and group by into an array.
  async getAllRefCodes() {
    const url = `${this.irRefCodes}`;
    const refCodes = [];
    let totalPage = 0;
    const params1 = new HttpParams().set('size', '20').set('page', `0`);
    await this.http.get(`${url}`, {params: params1 }).toPromise().then((data) => {
      console.log(data['page'].totalPages);
      console.log(data['page'].totalElements);
      totalPage = data['page'].totalPages;
    });
    for (let x = 0; x < totalPage; x++) {
     this.getRefCodesByPage(refCodes, url, x);
     console.log('Done');
    }
    await Promise.all(refCodes);
    console.log(refCodes);
  }

  // Getting all ref codes from API per page.
  async getRefCodesByPage(refCodes, url, pageNumber) {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('size', '20').set('page', `${pageNumber}`);
    const promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${url}`, {params: params})
    .toPromise().then((refCodeData) => {
      const refCode = refCodeData['_embedded'].refCodes;
       refCodes.push(...refCode);
    });
      resolve();
      return promise;
    });
    await Promise.all(promise);
  }
```

Wish to get all the record each time. Constant

Comment: Any reason for not using Observables and subscribe?

Comment: Well, I only wanted to run the request one time and then kill it when done. Also, the API only returns 20 results at a time so i am running it in a for loop to get all the pages at one time and then return a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

1. Changing the structure from promise to observables
2. Moving the for loop to get ref code by page inside the subscribe block (This is the main issue in your code I *think*)

   ```
     getAllRefCodes() {
       const url = `${this.irRefCodes}`;
       const refCodes = [];
       let totalPage = 0;
       const params1 = new HttpParams().set('size', '20').set('page', `0`);
       this.http.get(`${url}`, {params: params1 }).subscribe((data) => {
         console.log(data['page'].totalPages);
         console.log(data['page'].totalElements);
         totalPage = data['page'].totalPages;

         for (let x = 0; x < totalPage; x++) {
           this.getRefCodesByPage(refCodes, url, x);
           console.log('Done');
          }

       });

       console.log(refCodes);}
   ```

   getRefCodesByPage(refCodes, url, pageNumber) {
       const params = new HttpParams().set('size', '20').set('page', `${pageNumber}`);
       this.http.get(`${url}`, {params: params}).subscribe((refCodeData) => {
         const refCode = refCodeData['_embedded'].refCodes;
          refCodes.push(...refCode);
       })